# Bootstrap 3 modal form not appearing

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this simple modal form done with Bootstap 3, and I have no clue why it's not appearing when I click on the button.

```
<div id="modal" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-header">  
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>  
        <h3>Some title</h3>  
    </div>  
    <div class="modal-body">  
        <form id="modal-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/mailing" data-remote="true" method="post">
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="span6">  

            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type="text" class="span6">  

            <label>Message:</label>
            <textarea type="text" class="span12" rows="4"></textarea>
        </form>
    </div> 
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Send</a>  
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

And this is the button that should make this modal window appear when clicked:

```
<p class="text-center">
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#modal" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                    Message me
    </a>
</p>
```

It is not much different to the example codes I've seen around the web, but I can't make the modal window to appear.

Any idea why it's not working?

Edit:

This is how I'm including the Bootstrap JS files:

```
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Are you including the Bootstrap JS file(s)?

Comment: Yes I am. I will edit my post showing how I include the Bootstrap js files.

Comment: Also, I've just noticed you've got the `hide` class on the modal _and_ `display: none`. Remove the `display: none` and it should (might) work

Comment: I've removed the `display: none`, but it's still not working.

Comment: Just had a gander at the [BS3 Modal docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) and it looks like you're using the old, 2.x HTML. Try it with the proper HTML as seen [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Comment: _"This is how I'm including the Bootstrap JS files:"_ Does those two lines of `code` looks like JS file(s)? Those are CSS files, Your page has no functionality (Dead) put `<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` between your `head` tags and it **must work**

Comment: You were right Adam Zapp. I hadn't included the JS files and now it works (well, I have also modified my code slightly according to Bojangles link). You may answer this question and will mark it as valid if you want.

Comment: Additional information : if you use <div class=row> in modal body modal wont open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have the js file of bootstrap. Those aren't js files but css files of bootstrap. Include this inside your body element just before the closing tag 
    < /body>

```
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

both css and js files are needed

Answer (score 6):

Try removing the class `hide` from the modal div:
`<div id="modal" class="modal fade in" style="display: none;">`

Answer (score 1):

Just in case somebody else has the "why-won't-this-crazy-thing-work" moment.
I had the same problem, but other modal forms were working.
Finally, I realized that I had server-side code to handle the button click as well as the modal stuff.  The server-side code won, unfortunately I didn't have nothing coded in there.

So, check for server-side code.